# How to enable Full Screen mode in Powershell ISE 4.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I did search on web but did not find a good solution.

Here, full screen means that the title bar is hidden.
If you use  cygwin in Windows, this is the mode when you press ALT+F11.

Comment: Have you tried [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/)?

Comment: not yet. Still try to figure out why ISE could not be full screened.

Comment: I would try out ConEmu, sounds like you can get ISE full-screen using that.

Answer (score 2):

The typical Alt+F11 (or Shift+Alt+Enter as used in VS) full screen mode is not supported by PowerShell ISE. Feel free to suggest this on the [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) site. If you do, post the URL back here. I'll vote on it.